# How to remove index.php?p= permanently?

Tags: url, config, htaccess

I discovered search engines found duplicate content on my domain due to URLs being output with `index.php?p=` and `index.php` in ADDITION to the clean URLs.

For example, I have:

1. `domain.com/index.php?p=about`
2. `domain.com/index.php/about`
3. `domain.com/about`

And the first two requests with `index.php?p=` and `index.php` shouldn't exist. Only the last request with `domain.com/about` should exist.

While I found help removing `index.php`, some URLs continue to include `?p=`.

So, now I still have:

1. `domain.com/?p=about`
2. `domain.com/about`

While all I want is:

1. `domain.com/about`

Note: This is happening to several pages and blog entries throughout the site. Not only URLs directed to `about`.

How may I remove `?p=` permanently from the remaining URLs?

Within .htaccess, I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/admin\b [NC] # Don't mess with admin requests
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Within craft/config/general.php, I have:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(

        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from this answer on Stack Overflow: 
[.htaccess mod_rewrite: rewriting querystring to path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219119/1013978)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/admin\b [NC] # Don't mess with admin requests
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Remove ?p=
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?(([^&\s]*&)*)p=([^&\s]+)&?([^\s]*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This not only reformats `/?p=about` as `/about`, but it also preserves other parts of the query string.

For example, `/?p=about&tag=stuff` and even `/?tag=stuff&p=about` both redirect to `/about?tag=stuff`.

Comment: If i use this then i cannot login to admin dashboard anymore.... Any idea?

Comment: If you are using a different url other than `/admin` to access your control panel, you will need to update line 6 above and replace "admin" with your custom control panel trigger.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/your-custom-cp-trigger\b [NC]`